# does this glued object exist?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

Say there is a square G with four vertices $(a,b,c,d)$. From the diagonal direction of the square, I try to glue the edges so that the directions of the arrows match. I am curious whether the object that follows the glue rules in the below figure:
[image: square]
In the last step, I don't think the object is a Sphere and I could not image how the object will look like. I think it does not exist: **the vertex $a$, $c$ and $b$ will be glued together while edges $ab$ and $bc$ are glued inversely, contradicting each other**. But maybe I am wrong? If it exists, how will it look like? thank you very much!

Comment: Why is it a contradiction?  It might not be possible in three-dimensional space, but that doesn't make the surface an impossible surface.  I didn't check, but this is likely either a projective plane or a Klein bottle.

Comment: I think projective plane or Klein bottle is when you do the symmetry vertically or horizontally not diagonally from the square. @MichaelBurr

Comment: It is still a Klein Bottle, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon
Specifically, you have $ABAB^{-1}$ (start from bottom left and navigating clockwise).

Comment: @JustinBenfield, that's a interesting point that somehow it doesn't matter to do symmetry from vertically or horizontally or diagonally.

Comment: Yea, that surprised me a bit too, but I only briefly saw this stuff at the end of my Topology class back in 2013.

Comment: There are lots of sets of gluings that make the same space.  They amount to cutting up the surface along different paths.  You can classify compact surfaces by their orientations and Euler characteristics.

Comment: @MichaelBurr nice points! I will check further and thank you!

Comment: @JustinBenfield How is that $ABAB^{-1}$? $da$ and $dc$ are the same edge, right? So starting clockwise from $d$, it would be $ABBA^{-1}$, wouldn't it? That makes it projective plane.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you were talking about _not_ gluing it like in the original picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of trying to glue the boundaries does not work (because the edges don't have matched orientations). But you can glue $(ab)$ to $(dc)$ and then $(da)$ to $(bc)$. This yields a Klein Bottle (why?).

Comment: yes, you are right if you glue $ab$ to $dc$ then you have a Klien Bottle. I am just curious what happens to do the gluing of the suqare diagonally not vertically or horizontally. thank you!

Comment: It seems very similar to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)

Comment: wow, that's a nice hint, thank you!